# Como hacer que Django al detectar que el perfil no esta completo, te lo haga completar?

Tags: python, django

tengo un problema. En la pagina que estoy haciendo con Django, quiero que cada usuario pueda ver sus datos y que los pueda modificar, y en caso de no tener los datos completos, que te envie a completar el perfil. Intente hacer este IF pero se ve que no funciona.

```
{{ user.username }}
{% if user.picture == Null %}
    {% url 'users:complete_perfil' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema, lo que hice fue hacer un middleware, que veia los datos del usuario, y si falta la foto, este te lleva a la pagina para completar el perfil.